# TreeView custom nodes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make in a TreeView (winforms) that each node will have in it a checkbox and two icons and text.
How I can implement this thing ? I am really a newbie c# programmer.
I have found this two that helped me to understand.

[treeNode](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Using_the_treeview.aspx)
[treeView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/DropDownTreeView.aspx?fid=318338&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26#xx0xx)
but how I can show my icons and check box one near another shifter little bit in X dimension?

Can you help me with some example how that thing can be implemented.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Customizing a tree view is not for the feint of heart.  But you're lucky, [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/treeviewadv.aspx) does exactly what you are asking for.